# Css - Text Input with icon box and radius

Tags: css

How can I get achieve this input box look in css?

[image]

This is what i've tried so far. I can't position the icon box on the right side:

```
.inputs {
  text-align: center;
}
.usericonbox {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #2af;
  float: right;
}
.inputs input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(120,120,120,0.5);
}
```

html

```
<div class="inputs">
<span class="usericonbox"></span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Username"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute positioning, moving the icon after the input in the markup, and adding a couple styles makes it work:

```
<div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    <span class="usericonbox"></span>
</div>

.inputs {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.usericonbox {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 42px;
    background-color: #2af;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
.inputs input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(120,120,120,0.5);
}
```

Here's a demo of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/2rqw4d68/

Comment: What about `relative` positioning? giving it a `top` value seems to get same result. is there any reason we should avoid that?

Comment: `relative` would be fine in this case - just align or float it to the right.

Comment: There is one problem though. If I add another input, the icon box would stick to the first input https://jsfiddle.net/1bu0g76a/

Comment: @xperator - You should add each input and icon set in their own div.  The icons will position relative to the container element.  You could rename `div.inputs` to `div.input` and add another `div.inputs` wrapper around them all